# PHP MySQL Form Insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a task management list for a project. I've created a form to add each task and echo it into a list.

I want to add a select tag to the form that will allow the user to select the size of the task (small, medium, large or extra large).

My database is set up with 3 columns a unique key that auto increments, description and status.

I want to manipulate the value of the the status at the same time I enter the description. For example selecting "small" from the drop down will give the task entered a value of "1" and a different appearance in the list than a description with a status of "2".

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    $query = "INSERT INTO `project1`.`tasklist` (
    `key` ,
    `description` ,
    `status`    
    )
    VALUES (
    NULL , '".$_GET["newToDo"]."', '".$_GET["status"]."'    
        );";
    mysql_query($query);
    header('Location: index.php');
?>

<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    foreach($_GET['toDone'] as $toDoKey) {
        $query = "UPDATE `project1`.`practice` SET `status` = '0' WHERE `tasklist`.`key` =".$toDoKey.";";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
        header('Location: index.php');
?>

<h1>Get stuff done!</h1>

<form action = "secondary.php" method="GET">
    <label for="newToDo">New To Do:</label>
    <input type="text" name="newToDo" id="newToDo" />

    <select name="taskSize">
    <option value="small" selected="selected">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="extraLarge">X-Large</option>
    </select>


    <input type="submit" />
    </form>



<h2>to do</h2>
<form action="toDone.php" method="GET">
<ul>    
   <?php 
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  `project1`.`tasklist` WHERE `status` = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['description'];
        echo "</li>";
    }
   ?>
    </ul>
<input type="submit" />


    <h2>done</h2>

    <ul id="dunzo"> 
       <?php 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM  `project1`.`tasklist` WHERE `status` = 0";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $row['description'];
            echo "</li>";
        }
       ?>
        </ul>
```

What I want is to change how each new row in the list looks based on what is selected in the dropdown.

Comment: What do you want exactly and what have you tried ?

Comment: Before you go and write a whole application from scratch and, doubtlessly, make innumerable mistakes, have you thought about using a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) as a starting point? If you can find one that fits your needs, you can get a lot more done.

Comment: I've added the code I have above.

Answer (score 0):

Dude just one thing to add to your code..

[Deprecation of mysql_ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info)